# Unknown path components using PHP to post on wall?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

This was working when I first set it up, and all of a sudden with no codebase changes stopped working.

https://graph.facebook.com/100002831466409/feed&message=TESTTTTT&access_token=AAABqaF6H4qMBAIR9zZC6JtHEeYyrK9ZBKaZAdu67zYwxysJH12d0sW0G4cxX552sRyZCttHvnGoAexLuOJ0XezSL1NMgiKhwuL90yR2sEAZDZD is the URL I use.

"error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /access_token=AAABqaF6H4qMBAIR9zZC6JtHEeYyrK9ZBKaZAdu67zYwxysJH12d0sW0G4cxX552sRyZCttHvnGoAexLuOJ0XezSL1NMgiKhwuL90yR2sEAZDZD"

Comment: Make sure you deactivate this access token. You just shared it online with a bunch of programmers. I think @Wing Lian's answer works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url is incorrect, need a ? instead of an &

https://graph.facebook.com/100002831466409/feed?message=TESTTTTT&access_token=AAABqaF6H4qMBAIR9zZC6JtHEeYyrK9ZBKaZAdu67zYwxysJH12d0sW0G4cxX552sRyZCttHvnGoAexLuOJ0XezSL1NMgiKhwuL90yR2sEAZDZD